# Corrupt Exchange Server Database - Errors 233, 107, 474 - I need to repair and move to a new server

Tags: windows-server-2008

Server 2008 R2 - Exchange Server 2010 SP3

I have a failed raid 5 Virtual disk and a disk IO failure on one drive, I cant add hdd's to the array due to the raid error, how can I move the Exchange Server database to another server. We have setup a new server from scratch and added Exchange Server 2010 SP3 that we want to transfer to but the database is saying corrupt and I need to move it somehow.

The physical Disk errors are:

- There is an unrecoverable medium error detected on virtual disk:
  Virtual Disk 1 (Virtual Disk 1) Controller 0 (PERC S100)
- Disk medium error detected: Physical Disk 0:1 Controller 0, Connector

How can I repair the errors and move the database from one server to another, I can't repair the raid so if i added a USB drive to the server and moved the database to that would that allow me to make the repair? The database is arount 33GB with 9 users.

Unfortunately we have been left in a mess with this server and we have no backups available, Please help!

The errors are:

> ERROR Event ID 233 At '30/11/2017 12:52:54', database copy 'Mailbox
>   Database 1674280758' on this server encountered an error. For more
>   information, consult the Event log for "ExchangeStoreDb" or
>   "MSExchangeRepl" events.

and

> ERROR Event ID 474 Information Store (2256) Mailbox Database
>   1674280758: The database page read from the file "C:\Program
>   Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V14\Mailbox\Mailbox Database
>   1674280758\Mailbox Database 1674280758.edb" at offset 35890987008
>   (0x000000085b450000) (database page 1095305 (0x10B689)) for 32768
>   (0x00008000) bytes failed verification due to a page checksum
>   mismatch.  The expected checksum was
>   [364c67614b536c4f:774e4273524c7036:665268367a536630:716f6b7230593142]
>   and the actual checksum was
>   [77737773a0144fb4:2225dddab9ba49f7:932a6cd5c9e4ea5e:5f0b5f0be852af99].
>   The read operation will fail with error -1018 (0xfffffc06).  If this
>   condition persists then please restore the database from a previous
>   backup.  This problem is likely due to faulty hardware. Please contact
>   your hardware vendor for further assistance diagnosing the problem.
>
> WARNING Event ID 107 Exchange Search Indexer has temporarily disabled
>   indexing of the Mailbox Database Mailbox Database 1674280758 (GUID =
>   df7ac33a-6ce1-4009-8e9b-8af5aa00acbd) due to an error
>   (Microsoft.Mapi.MapiExceptionJetErrorReadVerifyFailure:
>   MapiExceptionJetErrorReadVerifyFailure: Unable to update CI Retry
>   table  (hr=0x80004005, ec=-1018) Diagnostic context:
>       Lid: 1494    ---- Remote Context Beg ----
>       Lid: 46077   dwParam: 0xAEE37
>       Lid: 46121   StoreEc: 0x8004010F
>       Lid: 55351   StoreEc: 0x8004010F
>       Lid: 53889   StoreEc: 0x8004010F
>       Lid: 59447   StoreEc: 0x8004010F
>       Lid: 43923   dwParam: 0xAEE37
>       Lid: 46077   dwParam: 0xAEE37
>       Lid: 46121   StoreEc: 0x8004010F
>       Lid: 55351   StoreEc: 0x8004010F
>       Lid: 53889   StoreEc: 0x8004010F
>       Lid: 59447   StoreEc: 0x8004010F
>       Lid: 43923   dwParam: 0xAEE37
>       Lid: 46077   dwParam: 0xAEE37
>       Lid: 46121   StoreEc: 0x8004010F
>       Lid: 55351   StoreEc: 0x8004010F
>       Lid: 53889   StoreEc: 0x8004010F
>       Lid: 59447   StoreEc: 0x8004010F
>       Lid: 43923   dwParam: 0xAEE37
>       Lid: 46077   dwParam: 0xAEE37
>       Lid: 46121   StoreEc: 0x8004010F
>       Lid: 55351   StoreEc: 0x8004010F
>       Lid: 53889   StoreEc: 0x8004010F
>       Lid: 59447   StoreEc: 0x8004010F
>       Lid: 43923   dwParam: 0xAEE37
>       Lid: 13300   StoreEc: 0xFFFFFC06
>       Lid: 61505
>       Lid: 22610   StoreEc: 0xFFFFFC06
>       Lid: 52115   dwParam: 0x9724B
>       Lid: 4000    StoreEc: 0xFFFFFC06
>       Lid: 16793   StoreEc: 0xFFFFFC06
>       Lid: 14126   StoreEc: 0xFFFFFC06
>       Lid: 1750    ---- Remote Context End ----
>       Lid: 10098   StoreEc: 0xFFFFFC06
>       Lid: 20226
>       Lid: 15346   StoreEc: 0xFFFFFC06    at Microsoft.Mapi.MapiExceptionHelper.ThrowIfError(String message, Int32
>   hresult, SafeExInterfaceHandle iUnknown, Exception innerException)
>   at Microsoft.Mapi.ExRpcAdmin.CiUpdateRetryTable(Guid mdbGuid, Guid
>   instanceGuid, UInt32[] documentIds, Guid[] mailboxGuids, Int32[]
>   hresults, Int16[] initialStates)    at
>   Microsoft.Exchange.Search.PropertyStore.UpdateRetryTable(PropertyStore
>   ps, UInt32[] docIds, Guid[] mailboxGuids, Int32[] hresults, Int16[]
>   initialStates, Object& unusedOut1, Object& unusedOut2)    at
>   Microsoft.Exchange.Search.PropertyStore.DoRetriableOperation[InParameter1Type,InParameter2Type,InParameter3Type,InParameter4Type,OutParameter1Type,OutParameter2Type,ReturnType](Guid
>   mdbGuid, InParameter1Type inParameter1, InParameter2Type inParameter2,
>   InParameter3Type inParameter3, InParameter4Type inParameter4,
>   OutParameter1Type& outParameter1, OutParameter2Type& outParameter2,
>   OperationDelegate`7 operationDelegate)    at
>   Microsoft.Exchange.Search.NotificationQueue.MoveBackloggedItemsToRetryTable()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Exchange.Search.NotificationQueue.MaintenanceProcedure()).

Answer (score 1):

The process here depends a little bit if your Exchange server is also broken or not. If the Server is broken you need to recover it as explained [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd876880(v=exchg.160).aspx). Once you have again a working MS Exchange server you can try to import the .EDB as explained [here](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/30825/Import-EDB-to-New-Exchange-Server-Move-MS-Exchange-Files-to-New-Server.html). After running eseutil and (hopefully) successfully restored the access you should create a new MailDB (.edb) and move all users (see [here](http://www.admin-enclave.com/en/articles/exchange/302-move-exchange-2010-2013-user-to-exchange-2016.html) for the comands) from the fixed (and possible halfbroken) .EDB / MailDB to a new one which is OK and not (half) broken!!!

By the way I would consider using [Exchange cache mode](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Turn-on-Cached-Exchange-Mode-7885af08-9a60-4ec3-850a-e221c1ed0c1c#ID0EAABAAA=2010) in your setup. If you do not have a backup then at least the users would have a local cache. Its not a backup, however having at least some emails locally is always better then having nothing. So this wouldn´t replace a working backup which is quite elementary.

If you couldn´t setup an additional Exchange Server or do think you do not need to restore that one as you would assume its working as designed. I would NOT create at first a USB drive copy from the damaged MailDB (.EDB). After that you can try to use eseutil to repair that database. I would start with an integrity check via (more infos [here](http://msexchangeguru.com/2009/07/12/exchange-database-recovery-using-eseutil-commands/)):

```
ESEUTIL /G "D:\Restore\priv1.edb“
```

*Offtopic: By the way, for only 9 users you really should consider using Exchange Online / Office 365 to avoid such issues again.*